# Envio de E-Mail pelo PHP Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

estou usando o PHP Mailer para envio de e-mail, no Outlook aparece o título e assunto corretamente, mas onde está grifado em vermelho aparece parte do código HTML que compõe o corpo do e-mail, gostaria que aparecesse da mesma forma que a mensagem grifada em verde.

Procurei muito tentando achar algo, mas nada, não sei se é a forma que estou procurando, mas isso já me consumiu muito tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A forma com que envio o e-mail é assim:

```
<?php

// Include PHP Mailer e Configurações

$mail->setFrom("FROM", "NAME_FROM");
$mail->addAddress("EMAIL", "NOME");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$subject = "ASSUNTO";
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = "HTML";
$mail->send();
$mail->ClearAddresses();

?>
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não tem nada de HTML onde está marcado em vermelho... Adicione na sua pergunta o valor que vc atribui à `$mail->Body`.

Comment: Se observar no final onde tem <https://www.yeb.com.br etc...> essa tag é um link que provavelmente foi modificada pelo Outlook para aparecer desta forma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido o problema...

O Outlook precisa de uma tag especial para esse texto, espero que isso ajude alguém.

```
<!--*|IF:MC_PREVIEW_TEXT|*-->
<!--[if !gte mso 9]>
<!---->
<span class="resumo" style="display:none; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; max-height:0px; max-width:0px; opacity:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;">TEXTO AQUI</span>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--*|END:IF|*-->
```